# EF6 Connected Scenario error : A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-6

I am doing a Desktop Application in WPF and as it is said in [Entity Framework Tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/persistence-in-entity-framework.aspx), it is a good idea to use the connected scenario.

So in my application, I have a class that has a static property Dal that contain the dbContext and all database access functions.

It was working well until I started to think about adding some async in the Dal, now I sometimes have this error even if it doesn't change the behavior in my application (just going faster as expected):

```
System.NotSupportedException: A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. 
Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. 
Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
```

I checked on every async call functions, everytime I call one, I use await.
I am also using db.SaveChangesAsync() in my Dal's functions.

Maybe I am wrong using a static property for my Dal ?

Comment: Connected scenario isn't the same as a static context. Usually it would be a context per window or module or whatever building blocks your app has. Anyway, without seeing a [mcve] this question can't be answered.